# Settings don't appear on windows startup

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a c# application that launches during startup with the next code below.
On the first windows form I have two textboxes that should be filled with data from `Properties.Settings.Default`, but they are empty.
If I close the app and start it again, the textboxes are filled with the correct values.
What can be the issue?

```
RegistryKey rk = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey
            ("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run", true);
rk.SetValue("", Application.ExecutablePath);
```

I set the values in the constructor of the form with the following code:

```
if (Properties.Settings.Default.dbusername != string.Empty)
{
    textBoxLoginUsername.Text = Properties.Settings.Default.dbusername;
    string readable = EncryptionHelper.Decrypt(Properties.Settings.Default.dbpassword);
    textBoxLoginPassword.Text = readable;
}
```

Comment: The constructor runs *before* any controls are created in `InitializeControls`. Even if you initialize `textBoxLoginUsername` in the constructor, its value will be replaced when `InitializeControls` runs.

Comment: If you want to load and display any data do so in the `Load` event, not the constructor. As for `EncryptionHelper.Decrypt`, that's a bad idea, no matter what that method does. Storing encrypted passwords just begs for a breach.  Besides, unless the end user supplies the decryption password, you'll have to store it *somewhere*. On Windows you can use Windows authentication to connect to databases using the current user's account, thus removing the need for stored passwords entirely. If you can't do that, the *user* should supply the password.

Comment: In the constructor I called a method to set the values after the InitializeComponent, now I moved it to the Load but the issue still persists. This used to work in the past, the values were set correctly after windows startup, and now it doesn't, although I haven't changed anything

Comment: `InitializeComponents` isn't called by the constructor. It's called by the runtime at the proper point in the form's lifecycle. When that happens, anything created in the constructor will be replaced. `I haven't changed anything` calling `InitializeComponents` in the constructor is a pretty serious change and a bug.

Comment: When I create a new form, VS adds code to InitializeComponent, which is called in the Form constructor. I usually set the stuff I need after this call. But even after I moved it to the Load, nothing changed. Any other ideas why this might be? Thanks

Comment: What happens if you add `Properties.Settings.Default.Reload();` right after `InitializeComponent()`, then bind the Controls to the settings, e.g., `textBoxLoginUsername.DataBindings.Add("Text", Properties.Settings.Default, "dbusername", false, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);`?

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't help either

Answer (score 0):

Your code shows a registry key assignment that is potentially problematic.

First, it attempts to set the *default* ("") value of
`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run`

It *should* be making named key for your startup app e.g.

[image: regedit-annotated]

Second, is it being set in the startup app itself? This is contrary to Microsoft [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/setupapi/run-and-runonce-registry-keys).

> Run and RunOnce Registry Keys -
> A program that is run from any of these keys should not write to the key during its execution because this will interfere with the execution of other programs registered under the key.

Instead, we'll "do the right thing" by establishing this key in the installer project for the app:

[image: do-the-right-thing]

Moving on...

---

**Settings**

Showing a "mystery line" like:

`string readable = EncryptionHelper.Decrypt(Properties.Settings.Default.dbpassword)`

makes it more difficult to diagnose the question that you *actually asked*. The points made by Panagiotis Kanavos are excellent, but notice that we're talking about *that* now instead of your original ask. I suggest you solve the main issue *first* using a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) leaving out the authentication scheme. Then we take the straightforward case of two startup settings:

[image: settings]

The textboxes are initialized here:

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        textBoxLoginUsername.Text = Properties.Settings.Default.dbusername;
        textBoxLoginPassword.Text = Properties.Settings.Default.dbpassword;
    }
}
```

And after *installing* the app and restarting the PC we see that things are "so far so good".

[image: restart]

---

**Things to check**

Without seeing more code, I can only make general suggestions.

1. Consider writing a startup log file to your app's AppData folder tracing values at various execution points.
2. Look for uncaught or "swallowed" exceptions that might skip your textbox initialization code.
3. Check for race condition where `Properties.Settings.Default.Save()` might be being called before textboxes are initialized.
4. Since there's "probably" a mechanism for saving login changes, make sure any event handlers are attached *after* the `InitializeComponents` has run. For example:

*Initializing a Persist scheme*

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        textBoxLoginUsername.Text = Properties.Settings.Default.dbusername;
        textBoxLoginPassword.Text = Properties.Settings.Default.dbpassword;
        buttonLogin.Click += onClickLogin;
    }
    private void onClickLogin(object? sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(tryLoginWithCredentials())
        {
            Properties.Settings.Default.dbusername = textBoxLoginUsername.Text;
            Properties.Settings.Default.dbpassword = textBoxLoginUsername.Text;
            Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
            Text = $"Logged in as {Properties.Settings.Default.dbusername}";
        }
    }
    private bool tryLoginWithCredentials() => true; // Succeeded (for testing purposes).
}
```

[image]